# Keyboard is not showing up when UIViewController is inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a strange problem. I have a `UIViewController` with `UITextField` and `UIWebView`. When I show it as a `window.rootController` and click either textfield or webview, keyboard shows up as expected, but when the same controller is presented from push segue, keyboard doesn't appear.

I tried to call `[self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible]`, but it didn't help. Another strange thing is that `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` handler is called. I examined application views hierarchy with Reveal App and noticed that `UIPeripheralHostView` is hidden and `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO`. If I set `hidden=NO` and `userInteractionEnabled=YES`, then keyboard appears on the screen and works as usual.

Any ideas about this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow subclassing UIWebView helped to resolve this issue.